# Can't connect to MQTT client, using client as global variable [Javascript, MQTT.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, mqtt.js

I'm working with MQTT.js and Mosquitto as my broker.

I'm trying to connect to my broker on the POST method and it works, storing the "Client" on the variable.

The problem is that the code doesn't work on the GET where my client isn't connecting and therefore, I can't subscribe or message to my topics.

I don't know what is the reason for that, but I solved it when I do de client connection inside the GET, but in this case, I don't want to do the connection inside the GET.

That's because the POST response is given when I login in the platform, and if I do the client connection on the GET that is for see the variables, always that I recharge the page It will connect again and then it will subscribe to the same topic, and after that when I send one message, if is subscribed three times to the same topic, it will Post 3 times.

PD: When I print the client inside the GET, It prints the same value that is assigned in the POST

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const request = require("request");

let mqtt = require('mqtt');
require("../requestMethods/get.js")();
require("../requestMethods/post.js")();

let client;
let options;

const postMqttData = async (string, body) => {
    const url = `http://localhost:8000/${string}`;
    const data = await postData(url, body)
    console.log(data)


}
const getToken = async (string) => {
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/tokenuser/${string}`
    const data = await requestData(url)
    const token = data;
    //console.log(token)
    return token;

}
router.post("/apiClientBroker", (req, res,next) => {
    let {user} = req.body;
    console.log(user)
    getToken(user).then(meta => {
        const { value } = meta.token[0];
        options = { username: user, password: value, clean: true, keepAlive: 60 }
        client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost', options);
        //console.log(client)
       })

})

router.get("/:user/:project",(req, res, next) => {
  //  clientBrokerResponse(req.client)
 // console.log(client)
    const { user } = req.params;
    const { project } = req.params;
    const uri = hostURL + "/variables/" + user + "/" + project;
    
    request.get(uri, (err, resp, body) => {
        //body = JSON.parse(body);

        if (err || resp.status == 500) {
            res.status(500).send({ ERROR: "Error searching" });
        } else {
            if (body.length) {
                const json= JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(client)
            client.on('connect', function () {
              
                for(let i= 0; i<json.length;i++){
                    const {deviceN}= json[i];
                    const {variableN}= json[i];
                    const {variableT}=json[i];
                    const topico = `${user}/${project}/${deviceN}/${variableN}`;
                    if(variableT==='Independiente'){
                       
                       
                            
                            client.subscribe(topico, function (err) {
                                console.log(`suscrito a ${topico}`)
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log("error en la subscripcion")
                                }
                            })
                            
                    
                       
                    }

                }
            })
                client.on('message', function (topic, message) {


                    // message is Buffer
                 
                        json1 = JSON.parse(message.toString()); //de esta manera se convierte el mensaje recibido en un json
                        console.log(json1);
                      //  if (json1.token === value) {
                            json2 = { 'value': json1.value }
                            postMqttData(`${topic}/${json1.token}`, json2)
                        
                            
        
                      //  } else {
                     //       console.log("Se está enviando a otro usuario el dato")
                      //  }
                    
        
                })
        

                res.status(resp.statusCode).send(body);
            } else {
                res
                    .status(404)
                    .send({ message: "Variables not found for this project" });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting the code in the `get` to do? If `client` already points to a connected session then the `on('connect'...)` function will probably not be called (because the connection is already up when you set the handler) and `on('message'...)` will also not be called (no subscription). Also how are messages being published to the broker (are you expecting a retained message to be waiting when you connect?). It would be helpful if you provide further detail on the problem you are trying to solve (i.e. what is the source of the messages, how should they be processed etc).

Comment: The GET method is a router to the variables of my user in the platform, therefore, it creates and gives to me the topic for subscribe. In this case my server creates automatically the topics because i'm using MQTT  like a simulation to send the data, and then the topic will be stored in the database through a POST. The issue is that I don't want to do the connection inside the GET because It will create a new connection every time that I refresh my variables route. Therefore I'm trying to create a "global client" that can store the connection with the broker once I had login session.

Comment: The issues is that an HTTP GET is a request/response (the GET request comes in, you respond with data) whereas MQTT is publish/subscribe (you subscribe and messages arrive over time). I think you need to reconsider your system architecture but its difficult to make suggestions due to the lack of information. A common approach is to make a single connection to the broker when the application starts and deal with incoming messages as the arrive (this may include storing data somewhere so it can be used to fulfil future GET request).